# How to add styles to only one element of a ul list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add additional styles to only one element of a list depending if the string matches with the url.

In this moment is identifying a unique string form a list and one element in the url, then it compare these two and add the styles depending if the strings are equal, but when doing this is applaying the style to all the elements in the list.

The result should add the styles only to the elements that match the string in the url.

```html
<ul class="__filter--list--categoria" style="display: block;">
  <li class="__filter--list--item">
    <a class="__anchor" href="/t/cervezas">Cervezas</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="__filter--list--item">
        <a class="__anchor" href="/t/cervezas/nacionales" style="background: red;">Nacionales</a>
      </li>
      <li class="__filter--list--item">
        <a class="__anchor" href="/t/cervezas/internacionales" style="background: red;">Internacionales</a>
      </li>
      <li class="__filter--list--item">
        <a class="__anchor" href="/t/cervezas/artesanales" style="background: red;">Artesanales</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
var currentUrl = window.location.href.split('/')[5];
var categoryName = $('.__filter--list--categoria .__filter--list--item li .__anchor');
var categoryArray = [];

$(categoryName).each(function() {
  categoryArray.push($(this).text())
});

for (x = 0; x < categoryArray.length; x++) {
  var categoryString = categoryArray[x].toLowerCase();
  if (categoryString === currentUrl) {
    console.log('EQUAL...')
    $(categoryName).css('background', 'red')
  } else {
    console.log('NOT EQUAL...')
  }
}
```

Comment: what's `currentUrl` value?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio currentUrl is the url in the browser, it split and take the fifth element of the index, this is use to match the elements in the list, for example if the url is http://0.0.0.0:5000/t/cervezas/nacionales, it will split by '/' and take the fifth element, in this case 'nacionales'

Comment: @Rezpo that's going to be rather brittle, you should probably use substring and lastIndexOf, `currentUrl = window.location.pathname.substring(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop li item by `each` method, and check href with testurl

```
let testurl = '/t/cervezas/nacionales';
$('li').each(function(index,item){
  let href = $(item).find('a').attr('href');
  if(href == testurl){
     $(item).css('border', '1px solid green');
  }
})
```

```js
let testurl = '/t/cervezas/nacionales';
$('li').each(function(index,item){
  let href = $(item).find('a').attr('href');
  if(href == testurl){
     $(item).css('border', '1px solid green');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="__filter--list--categoria" style="display: block;">
  <li class="__filter--list--item">
    <a class="__anchor" href="/t/cervezas">Cervezas</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="__filter--list--item">
        <a class="__anchor" href="/t/cervezas/nacionales" style="background: red;">Nacionales</a>
      </li>
      <li class="__filter--list--item">
        <a class="__anchor" href="/t/cervezas/internacionales" style="background: red;">Internacionales</a>
      </li>
      <li class="__filter--list--item">
        <a class="__anchor" href="/t/cervezas/artesanales" style="background: red;">Artesanales</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain what is causing the issue, your problem is with this line:
`$(categoryName).css('background', 'red')`
This is applying the background red to every element that matches the categoryName selector, which is all your anchor tags.  You don't currently have a class that uniquely identifies the different url's, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56634800/264607 for a way to loop through your li elements and apply the style to the correct one